# sending bike from Brighton, UK to Berlin, Germany

Tags: europe, bicycles, shipping

We are moving from Brighton, United Kingdom to Berlin, Germany. We will first fly somewhere else, so we cannot take the bikes on the plane with us. The most important thing is to find a cheap solution. The bikes are not worth that much here in the UK, but they are worth more in Berlin. I do not own a bike bag, but I guess I could find a carton box at a local bike shop.

**What is a cheap solution to get 2 bikes from Brighton, UK to Berlin, Germany?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about freighting goods, not travelling.

Comment: There might be useful information on [expatriates.se]